# Comparison Theorem for Integrals

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, proof-verification

Problem: Let $a>0$ and $b>a+1$. Use the Comparison Theorem to show that the following integral is convergent:

$$\int ^ \infty _0 \frac{x^a}{1+x^b} \ dx$$

My attempt at this was that since $b>a+1$, $$\frac{x^a}{x^b}=\frac{1}{x^{b-a}}$$
So

$$\int ^ \infty _0 \frac{1}{x^{b-a}} \ dx \gt \int ^ \infty _0 \frac{x^a}{1+x^b} \ dx$$

Let

$$\int ^ \infty _0 \frac{1}{x^{b-a}} \ dx= \int ^ \infty _0 \frac{1}{x^{p}} \ dx$$ 
Since $b-a > 1$, as $a>0$ and $b>a+1$,  $\ p>1$
and therefore by the Comparison Theorem,  $$\int ^ \infty _0 \frac{x^a}{1+x^b} \ dx$$ converges.

Is my logic and reasoning correct?

EDIT after Mustafa Said's comment:

since $b>a+1$, $$\frac{x^a}{x^b}=\frac{1}{x^{b-a}}$$

and that the original integral is improper, so we can split it up.

$$\int ^ \infty _0 \frac{x^a}{1+x^b} \ dx=\int ^ 1 _0 \frac{x^a}{1+x^b} \ dx +\int ^ \infty _1 \frac{x^a}{1+x^b} \ dx$$

The first integral of the right hand side is clearly definite, so we need to prove the second integral of the right hand side converges

So

$$\int ^ \infty _1 \frac{1}{x^{b-a}} \ dx \gt \int ^ \infty _1 \frac{x^a}{1+x^b} \ dx$$

Let

$$\int ^ \infty _1 \frac{1}{x^{b-a}} \ dx= \int ^ \infty _1 \frac{1}{x^{p}} \ dx$$ 
Since $b-a > 1$, as $a>0$ and $b>a+1$,  $\ p>1$
and therefore by the Comparison Theorem,  $$\int ^ \infty _0 \frac{x^a}{1+x^b} \ dx$$ converges.

Comment: Looks OK to me...

Comment: Good to know!  +1

Comment: Some of your integrals are improper but this can be fixed.  Just split the integral over $[0,1]$ and $[1, \infty)$ and then apply your reasoning to the second integral since the first is clearly finite.

Comment: Alright I edited my original post to make that change

Comment: @MustafaSaid Right, I missed that. Should have looked more closely...

Comment: Will I need to use a limit to represent the split integral of $[1, \infty]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**This is a comment and not an answer to the post**

Just for your curiosity, the antiderivative is given without any restriction by
$$\frac{x^{a+1} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{a+1}{b};\frac{a+1}{b}+1;-x^b\right)}{a+1}$$ and the integral between $0$ and $\infty$ is given by $$\frac{\pi  \csc \left(\frac{\pi  (a+1)}{b}\right)}{b} $$ if $\Re(a-b)<-1\land \Re(a)>-1$

Comment: That's very interesting, but could you explain what "without any restriction" means?

Comment: Apparently, at least to me, the antiderivative is valid for any $a$ and any $b$ while restrictions apply to the integral.